# Precise adjusting of two colours simultaneously via manipulation with brightness, contrast and gamma

Tags: image, image-processing, colors

I have a black and white image which has to be rendered on screen as grayscale image of precise colours. Black should be displayed as rgb(40,40,40) and white as rgb(128,128,128).

The problem is the software to render this image does not allow colours to be specified directly; the only parameters I can vary are brightness, contrast and gamma (converting image to the desired colours is not an option).

Is there any formulae to calculate specific values for those parameters to adjust colours as desribed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing how they compute brightness and contrast, it is hard to tell you how to do your computation.

Perhaps I still misunderstand. But you can find the min and max values in your image using Imagemagick

```
convert image -format %[fx:255*minima] info: 

convert image -format %[fx:255*maxima] info:
```

Those will be in the range of 0 to 255.

As Mark showed above the transformation is linear. So it obeys the equation

```
Y = a*X + b
```

**where a is a measure of contrast and b is a measure of brightness; X is your input value and Y is your desired output value.**

Thus

```
Ymax = a*Xmax + b
```

and

```
Ymin = a*Xmin + b
```

Subtracting and solving for a, we get

```
a = (Ymax-Ymin)/(Xmax-Xmin)
```

and substituting that into the equation for Ymax and saving for b, we get

```
b = Ymax - a*Xmax = Ymax - ( (Ymax-Ymin)/(Xmax-Xmin) )*Xmax
```

Then you can use the Imagemagick function -function polynomial to process your image.

In unix, I would do it as follows

```
Xmin=$(convert image -format %[fx:255*minima] info:)

Xmax=$(convert image -format %[fx:255*maxima] info:)
```

If your image is pure black and pure white, then you can skip the above and just use

```
Xmin=0

Xmax=255
```

And your desired values are

```
Ymin=40

Ymax=128
```

These are now variables and I can use -fx to do the calculations for a and b

```
a = $(convert xc: -format "%[fx:($Ymax-$Ymin)/($Xmax-$Xmin)]" info:)

b = $(convert xc: -format "%[fx:$Ymax - $a*$Xmax]" info:)
```

And to convert your image,

```
convert image -function polynomial "$a,$b" result image
```

Comment: Nice answer! Keep them coming please.

Comment: @fmw42 Thank you very much! Your detailed explanation is precisely what I was hoping for. Your formulae work and my problem (by the way, very serious one for me) is finally solved.

Comment: Sure thing, just clicked it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In general, there are several ways to alter an image's contrast, gamma and brightness and it is difficult to know which method your chosen tool uses, and therefore provide the correct answer.

What you are trying to do is move the blue line (no contrast or brightness changes) in the image below to where the red line (decreased contrast) is:

[image]

In general, *decreasing* the contrast will *rotate* the blue line *clockwise* whereas *increasing* it will *rotate* it *anti-clockwise*. In general, *increasing* the *brightness* will *shift* the blue line to the *right* whereas *decreasing* the *brightness* will *shift* it *left*. Changing the gamma will likely make the line into a curve.

Can you use **ImageMagick** at the commandline instead?

```
convert input.png +level 15.69%,50.2% -depth 8 result.png
```

If you have v7+, use `magick` in place of `convert`.

---

I made a little gradient for you with:

```
convert -size 60x255 gradient: -rotate 90 gradient.png
```

[image]

And if you apply the suggested command:

```
convert gradient.png +level 15.69%,50.2% -depth 8 result.png
```

You will get this:

[image]

And you can check the statistics (min and max) with:

```
identify -verbose result.png | more

Image: result.png
  Format: PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
  Mime type: image/png
  Class: PseudoClass
  Geometry: 255x60+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Type: Grayscale
  Base type: Palette
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: Gray
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    Gray: 8-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 15300
    Gray:
      min: 40 (0.156863)                        <--- MIN looks good
      max: 128 (0.501961)                       <--- MAX looks good
      mean: 84.0078 (0.329443)
      standard deviation: 25.5119 (0.100047)
      kurtosis: -1.19879
      skewness: 0.000197702
```

Comment: `@MarkSetchell`This will only work on Q8 install of imagemagick where the quantumrange is 0 to 255. For Q16, the default, you would need to specify values for -level in the quantumrange of 0 to 65535. I always recommend using percents for portability. So 40 goes to 100*40/255=15.69% and 128 goes to 100*128/255=50.20%. See http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#level. The -depth does not force -level to use values of 0 to 255 for Q16 compiles. It only sets the values for the output image range.

Comment: @fmw42 Many thanks for the correction. I have tried to improve my answer.

Comment: Thank you for advices, but, maybe, I did not make myself clear, it is not about how to properly convert images. Due to copyright issues, I am not allowed to modify them anyhow. Moreover, those images files are not bmp or tiff or something. Special software is to be used to show them (done intentionally, I presume). The only rendering parameters the software allows to change are brightness, contrast and gamma. So my question is about formula (wonder whether it exists); how to calculate values for those parameters to adjust colours as I described in the original post.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I wrote my comment before you updated your answer (or I refreshed this page). Unfortunately, it does not answer my question, but I just want to let you know that I am very grateful for your explanation anyway.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you, Mark! I really apppreciate your aid and thankful for the time you spent. You and fmw42 helped me greatly.